# Performing a LIKE operation only on columns of the supported type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

[Homework]

I have written a `plpgsql` function that takes a table name as input for each column in that table runs some query involving the `LIKE` operator.

For tables containing columns with types such as `integer` I get the following, unsurprising, error:

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown`

This makes sense, since `LIKE` makes no sense on an integer type.

I could check to make sure that the type of each column is not `integer, date, ...` however it seems hacky to hardcode the data types that do / do not support the `LIKE` operation, i.e that are not "*textual*". Additionally, there are a lot of custom data types used in the DB that represent strings of some sort.

I'm wondering what would be a good way to approach this issue. Is there a way to check that a certain column of some type can support a `LIKE` query?

Comment: The simple solution would be to cast each column to text: `column::text`.

Comment: If you want to get fancy, you can explore the `information_schema` information on operators, functions, data types, and type casts. It should be possible - albeit somewhat complicated - to determine whether there's an implementation of `LIKE` for a given pair of input data types, or an implicit cast to one from a supported type. The `LIKE` operator is converted to the operator `~~` at parse-time, so that's what you'd have to look up in `information_schema`. It's possible you'll need to use `pg_catalog` tables and views instead, if `information_schema` doesn't have all the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that is possible to check if generically a type supports the LIKE operator, but you can always run the query and trap the error if it occurs .

The LIKE operator throws in this case a `undefined_function` error. You can catch this error within a a exception block and do something else instead. See this example function:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN      
  BEGIN -- begin of the exception block
    PERFORM 1 LIKE '10'; --  <--this code throws a exception
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN undefined_function THEN
        RAISE WARNING '%', 'could not execute query!';
  END;  -- end of the exception block
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See for more info the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) and the [list all error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html)